# How to capture dynamic Values in Jmeter while executing the scriting?

Tags: jmeter

In Application,  I have recorded the script in jmeter. some values are non editable in application. those values will change as per selection in CSV file input. Those values how can i capture while executing.

Answer (score 0):

Learn Jmeter in 60 Minutes is a webinar I gave a few months ago that explains JMeter from scratch and also covers capturing and using dynamic values in JMeter.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cv7KqxaLZd8